# What the format should look like for a Function Import Response which returning a simple type?

Tags: odata

I'm really struggling with the format of a Function Import response. So far, I only saw the spec mentioned that the response of an Function Import could be a Simple type.

But I did not see any real odata service did that. So, I don't know what the response format looks like.

Is there anyone can share me a Function Import Response with returning a simple type, such as String or Integer?

(Screenshot is OK, and ATOM+XML format is better.)

I do appropriate anyone's help.

Thanks,

Xianyi Ye

Comment: Which version are you using? I have a simple sample about the unbound function. You can refer it [here](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/tree/master/UnboundFunctionConventionRouting)

Comment: V3 is preferred. But either V2 or V4 is also acceptable.